# Delete Rows from a Constrained Reference Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to delete an object from a table (NewClubProspect) that has reference rows in a table called NewClubProspectNewClubEmail

**The error I am getting is**

```
        The DELETE statement conflicted with the 
        REFERENCE constrain
 "FK_dbo.NewClubProspectNewClubEmail_dbo.NewClubProspect_NewClubProspect_Id" 

        The conflict occurred in database 
        "Reporting", table "dbo.NewClubProspectNewClubEmail", column 'NewClubProspect_Id'.
        The statement has been terminated.
```

The reference table looks like this:
[image]

I can solve the problem this way but would rather not use straight SQL. I have removed the try/catches for brevity:

```
  //Delete out of the reference table first         
   var sql = "delete from NewClubProspectNewClubEmail where NewClubProspect_Id = @p0";
   var r = ReportingDBTasks.Query(sql,prospect.Id);

   //Delete the parent object
    db.NewClubProspects.Remove(prospect);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

How can I delete from the reference table using EF instead of straight SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to enable cascading deletes on the constraint. But I suppose cascades were turned off for a reason, so I'm pretty sure you still have to do this the old fashioned way and delete each one.

Assuming you have a navigation property, it should be something like:

```
foreach(var nce in prospect.NewClubEmails)
    db.NewClubProspectNewClubEmails.Remove(nce); 

db.NewClubProspects.Remove(prospect);
db.SaveChanges();
```